# It is possible to show the estimated time, kbs, mb, while uploading the file to server using Asynctask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am uploading video file to server using AsyncTask and my goal here is i want to display a estimated time and how many Megabytes uploaded per seconds to server so users can know how long it takes to be uploaded, I have a sample code that can show the percentages of the uploaded file, can anyone guide me how to achieve this, any help is much much appreciated. thanks

I see this code :

```
private class UploadFileToServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            prog_percentage.setProgress(0);
            super.onPreExecute();
        }
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
            prog_percentage.setProgress(progress[0]);
            percentage.setText(String.valueOf(progress[0]) + "%");
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            return uploadFile();
        }
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        private String uploadFile() {
            String responseString = null;
            try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Config.FILE_UPLOAD_URL_FOR_IMAGE);

                Log.i("UploadApp", "upload url: " + Config.FILE_UPLOAD_URL_FOR_IMAGE);

                AndroidMultiPartEntity entity;
                entity = new AndroidMultiPartEntity(
                        new AndroidMultiPartEntity.ProgressListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void transferred(long num) {
                                publishProgress((int) ((num / (float) totalSize) * 100));
                            }
                        });
                File sourceFile;
                sourceFile = new File(selectedFilePath);

                // Adding file data to http body
                entity.addPart("image", new FileBody(sourceFile));

                totalSize = entity.getContentLength();
                httppost.setEntity(entity);

                // Making server call
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();

                int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                if (statusCode == 200) {
                    // Server response
                    responseString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);
                } else {
                    responseString = "Error occurred! Http Status Code: " + statusCode;
                }
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                responseString = e.toString();
                Log.e("UploadApp", "exception: " + responseString);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                responseString = e.toString();
                Log.e("UploadApp", "exception: " + responseString);
            }
            return responseString;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }
```

Comment: 'upload kbs or mb' ??? What would that be?

Comment: Yes the initial size upload of the file

Comment: size upload ???? Never heard of.

Comment: I need to show the initial uploaded of the file and the estimated time, where i should start, can you provide a link of tutorial a pseudo code, your help is much helpful to me.

Comment: I need to show the estimated time while uploading a file

Comment: What is 'initial uploaded of the file' ? 'estimated time' of?? And what is kbs and mb? You could finally rephrase what you want so all is clear.

Comment: Ok. You mean the estimated upload time? Now tell what your problem is exactly. Can't you CALCULATE all those things? Or don't you know how to SHOW them? And what is kbs? And what is mb?

Comment: while uploaddir ????

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/display-progress.html

Comment: I've google it how to calculate the bytes per seconds and how to get the estimated upload time using system.nanoTime and get the bytes per second but i don't know where i should start and I already display the upload percentage sorry for my bad grammar

Comment: If you can display a percentage, then why cant you display a time? You are not telling WHY you have problems doing this.

Comment: Sorry i'm just a beginner of android development the above code its not mine, I understand a little of the logic behind using Asynctask but its hard to modify the AndroidMultiPartEntity

Comment: I need to study more of how to use the Asynctask and  all the parameters, but your suggestion and comment it is very helpful to me. and know i need to try more

Comment: You should have told right away that you found AndroidMultipartEntity class on androidhive. That's the way it goes here. If you can calculate all in transferred() than you can display those values in an extra TextView above and under the ProgressBar. Add it to the xml layout file.

Answer (score 1):

Your line

```
publishProgress((int) ((num / (float) totalSize) * 100));
```

actually computes the percentage out of the uploaded size, so you'd have to pass 'num' to the progress instead of the computation result. Then you can compute all values you want on this side.